# To Manage disaster have implemented 2 stack unable to access bucket getting access denied get object?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have created 2 stack strategies so that it will deploy in two regions but here the issue is that when my stack gets deployed it will create two roles in the respective region and also the resources. but the things is when I am trying to access the bucket from east to west through lambda handler I am able to acces the bucket but when I am trying to access west to east it throwing access denied (get object) error.
to achieve this I have applied bucket policy to both the bucket and also have attached the managed policy to respective role .

Please share your thoughts ??

have stucked in this secanrio from couple of days.

Comment: errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied",
  "errorType": "ClientError",
  "

Comment: I am using aws-cdk with python